# Как воспроизвести звук при Destroy(gameObject)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется следующая функция. При касании персонажа об объект (монета), то он уничтожается. Нужно, чтобы при уничтожении проигрывал звук "mainSound"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class money : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int countC; // установим цену нашей монеты (т.е. какое количество монет будет прибавляться при сборе определенной монеты)
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource mainSound;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    { 
        // триггер монеты, реагирует при взаимодействии с монетой (при входе игрока в триггер нашей монеты)
        money_cat.money += countC; // добавляем монеты в указанную ссылку
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<money_cat>().TextMoney.text = money_cat.money.ToString(); // вывод количеста монет на экран
        Destroy(gameObject);
        mainSound.Play();
    }

}
```

Comment: А что сейчас не работает?

Comment: Объект не звучит, потому, что уничтожен.

Comment: @ssa112112, при уничтожении объекта игра уходит в стоп

Answer (score 3):

Вы уничтожаете объект, использующий `AudioSource`. Решения:

- Не уничтожать объект, а просто сделать `disable` и уничтожить его после того, как мелодия проиграется (надо узнать длину трека проигрывания предварительно, конечно)
- Создать глобальный объект с различными аудио ресурсами игры и проигрывать звук оттуда
- Перед уничтожением объекта, создать (инстанциировать) пустой объект, прикрепить туда AudioSource и проиграть звук. Большой недостаток в этом: каждый instantiate и destroy сильно сказывается на fps и пустышку с звуком так-же придётся уничтожить по завершению
- Использовать `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint static function` ([AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html)). Эта функция создаёт `audio source`, но автоматически уничтожается, после того как клип проиграется

Также метод [Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html), вторым параметром принимает значение, задержку уничтожения объекта. Поэтому вторым параметром можно указать длину проигрываемого звука и вызвать его к примеру так:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false; // суперкласс для всех видов рендера
GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false; // суперкласс для всех видов коллайдеров
mainSound.Play();    
Destroy(gameObject, mainSound.clip.length);
```

Comment: @Yaroslav можно объяснение вашей правки по поводу `GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;  GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;` ?

Comment: Если сделать объект `disable`, то и все его компоненты, включая `AudioSource` будут отключены. Соответственно нужно отключить только визуализацию и реакцию на столкновения, словно на сцене объекта и нет вовсе.

Comment: ок. сойдёт...))